# jquery each iterates even if no elements found

Tags: jquery

Here is simple jquery loop:

```
$('input:checked[name*="bulk"]').each(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut(1800);
});
```

All works fine if there are some checkboxes checked but if no it fades out whole container. Why each keep working even if no elements found?

Comment: Works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WuFug/).

Comment: when I do alert($('input:checked[name*="bulk"]').length) just before each it displays 0

Comment: What's the HTML look like? Can you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: Put an alert inside the loop to see if it's being called. I suspect some other code is actually causing the fadeout.

Comment: Maybe there's another part in your code that can fade the element which is executed every time?

Comment: this so weired now it works fine I suppose its some caching or so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`each` iterates over the length of the collection. When the length is 0, `each` will successfully call the function 0 times and return the empty collection.

So, if the function is being called, the selector is matching *something*.

Comment: How does that explain the behavior he's seeing, where it's fading out the whole collection?

Comment: @Barmar how does that statement fit the title "no elements found" the question is paradoxical. Though this does not solve the puzzle it does point in the right direction. Ie the elements iterated over are those that the selector matches

Comment: when I do alert($('input:checked[name*="bulk"]').length) just before each it displays 0